# Chrome : open chrome with insecure origin option

Tags: google-chrome

i am trying

```
chrome "http://example.com" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as secure="http://example.com" --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir
```

but still it is not opening it with insecure origin.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Press `Win + R`

and type

`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`